Azure function with serviceBusTrigger 5 minute to restart after DrainMode/stop
I have a Azure function (Consumer plan) that should trigger on Service bus event but i see in the logs that Aazure functions is stopped and drain and it take 5 minutes for the azure function to start why do it take so long for the function to restart when there is message in the queue
11/3/2024, 3:32:21.342 PM DrainMode mode enabled

11/3/2024, 3:32:21.343 PM Calling StopAsync on the registered listeners

11/3/2024, 3:32:21.346 PM Stopping the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.Listeners.ServiceBusListener' for function '**
 
11/3/2024, 3:32:21.389 PM Stopped the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.Listeners.ServiceBusListener' for function '******
 
11/3/2024, 3:32:21.391 PM Call to StopAsync complete, registered listeners are now stopped
 
11/3/2024, 3:32:21.426 PM Stopped the listener 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus.Listeners.ServiceBusListener' for functio 
 
11/3/2024, 3:32:21.428 PM Call to StopAsync complete, registered listeners are now stopped

11/3/2024, 3:38:38.016 PM Initializing Warmup Extension.
 
11/3/2024, 3:38:38.031 PM Initializing Host. OperationId: '*****'.
 
11/3/2024, 3:38:38.032 PM Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=3, Oper 9
 
11/3/2024, 3:38:38.056 PM ApplicationInsightsLoggerOptions {


Check if my SO solution helps.

Please share your function code @lars1595

Check if below solution helps @lars1595.

Drain mode in Service Bus trigger Azure Function is a feature available to avoid conflicts when processing the messages, refer my SO answer.
For Consumption and Elastic Premium Plans, the scale controller decides the scaling behavior. Drain mode will be enabled when the scale controller decides to scale down a worker during less load. This is to avoid the conflicts when you need to perform updates on the function without losing any messages or leading to errors.
When drain mode is enabled:

The function will stop picking up new messages from the Service Bus entities.
It continues processing messages which are already being handled until completed.
The function will stop completely once all the in-progress messages are processed.

At this time, it sends a request to the Admin API to enter drain mode and all the currently executing Functions on that instance receive a cancellation token that can be handled using below code. This allows the function to finish the ongoing tasks before it is stopped, refer MSDOC.
Code Snippet:
public async Task Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("queuename", Connection = "servicebusconnectionstring")]
    ServiceBusReceivedMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken,
    ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
{
    try
    {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("A cancellation token was received. Taking precautionary actions.");

            //Take precautions like noting how far along you are with processing the batch

            _logger.LogInformation("Precautionary activities --complete--.");
            }
            else
            {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Message: {message} was processed.");
            _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Something unexpected happened: {ex.Message}");
    }
    await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
}

Output:
Functions:

Function1: serviceBusTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.  
[2024-11-27T12:01:41.929Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000xxx9'.  
[2024-11-27T12:01:48.096Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='(null)', Id=40efdb2a-6fe2-44b6-9071-8ec096e7e029)  
[2024-11-27T12:01:48.101Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: 9734a2b8ff754ecea689d9ce05ed331b, SequenceNumber: 1, DeliveryCount: 1, EnqueuedTimeUtc: 2024-11-27T12:01:44.7220000+00:00, LockedUntilUtc: 2024-11-27T12:02:44.9400000+00:00, SessionId: (null)  
[2024-11-27T12:01:48.603Z] Message: {MessageId:9734a2b8ff754ecea689d9ce05ed331b} was processed.  
[2024-11-27T12:01:48.608Z] Message ID: 9734a2b8ff754ecea689d9ce05ed331b  
[2024-11-27T12:01:48.614Z] Message Body: Hello World  
[2024-11-27T12:01:48.620Z] Message Content-Type: (null)  
[2024-11-27T12:01:48.649Z] Start processing HTTP request POST [http://127.0.0.1:64966/Settlement/Complete](http://127.0.0.1:64966/Settlement/Complete "http://127.0.0.1:64966/settlement/complete")  
[2024-11-27T12:01:48.658Z] Sending HTTP request POST [http://127.0.0.1:64966/Settlement/Complete](http://127.0.0.1:64966/Settlement/Complete "http://127.0.0.1:64966/settlement/complete")  
[2024-11-27T12:01:49.184Z] Received HTTP response headers after 506.2569ms - 200  
[2024-11-27T12:01:49.195Z] End processing HTTP request after 550.2789ms - 200  
[2024-11-27T12:01:49.257Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=40efdb2a-6fe2-44b6-9071-8ec096e7e029, Duration=1242ms)

